# Maintaining session between subdomains in Laravel PHP and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, session, angularjs, laravel-4

Not specifically a Laravel issue I guess but it's the PHP framework I'm using.

I have the following subdomains: `app.hostname.dev` and `api.hostname.dev`

I have a laravel PHP app with an API on api. and an AngularJS SPA app on app.

If I create a session variable on the API it's only available to that subdomain. If I do a GET AJAX request from the front-end the var_dump below returns NULL. If I change my API endpoint to the same subdomain (app.hostname.dev) I get the correct session variable.

```
//Session::put('test', 'TESTING');
var_dump(Session::get('test'));
```

Here are my laravel session settings:

```
'driver' => 'cookie', // also tried database
'path' => '/',
'domain' => '.hostname.dev',
```

Here are my AngularJS settings:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

I thought the settings above would be enough to ensure cross domain sessions?

**UPDATE**

Issue is not a cross domain problem but seems more like a fact that the request is coming via ajax. As a seession var created  on `app.` is available on `api.` however unavailable to either via ajax get request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was not setting `withCredentials: true;` on Angular side and not having `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on my server.

Cookies weren't being sent with the request.

In angular config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

In my routes.php in laravel:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Comment: Better to put the `header(...)` in `app/filters.php` in `App::before` which runs before the request. Routes.php shouldn't be responsible for or care about the header so leave it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running your sub-domains on the same box right?

And you are using cookie through PHP right? If so, what are your cookie root domain (http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

If your cookie domain is set to root "hostname.dev" then it should be available in both your sub domains.

Comment: Yeah it's actually part of the same project as well. I've set the cookie domain via the Laravel session config. I tried .hostname.dev and also without the ```.```